# Meaning of the word ' itular'

Tags: meaning, etymology

While looking up synonyms of the word 'so-called', I stumbled upon '[itular](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/itular)', of which I've never heard, and for which I can't seem to find additional (digital) sources. The dictionary itself gives a [misspelling](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=itular).

My first hunch was that it's a misspelling of 'titular', but, based on the synonyms, they seem to have different definitions.

Does anyone recognize the word, or can anyone provide a definition and/or an etymology of the word?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but this is clearly a data error—if you view the entry for any of the purported synonyms of *itular*, the link back is to *titular*; Reference.com's entry is erroneous; no such word can be found in the OED or any major dictionary, and a search on Google Books turns up only transcription errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a fault in an online resource.

Comment: That all seems to make perfect sense, thanks for the heads up and sorry for the inconvenience. Shall I delete, or is it better practice to let it be closed down?

Comment: @Joaachim No trouble at all, please feel welcome back at any time.

Answer (score 1):

By analogy with table/tabular, title/titular, and so on, "itular" should mean "having the properties of an itle".  But since there is no such thing as an "itle", "itular" doesn't mean anything.